# How to show that there is no positive rational number a such that $a^3$ = 2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm stuck on this one.
So far, I've tried this:
\begin{align}
a^3 &= 2 \\
a &= \left(\frac mn\right) \\ 
a^3 &= \left(\frac mn\right)^3 = 2 \\
m^3 &= 2n^3 \\
m &= 2p \\
m^3 &= (2p)^3
\end{align}
I'm really confused about what to do after this—the book answer says that $m^3$ becomes $m^3 = 2(4p)^3$. And $2n^3 = 2(4p)^3$. I'm super confused here and can't really understand what's going on here.

Can someone tell what exactly is going on here and how should I prove this?

Comment: I don't think the book says what you say it says. Then again, nothing is impossible. Ignore the book. Do the same as in the similar problem with $a^2=2$.

Comment: After $m=2p$, (which you know because $m^3$ is even), you should substitute $2p$ for $m$, not for $2n^3$. You would get $(2p)^3 = 2n^3$. Go from there, mimicking the proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.

Comment: I haven't written the exact answer. Just things I didn't understand. It's from Serge Lang's Basic Mathematics. The book says it's not possible that $a^3 = 2$ because of some rules that I still haven't understood properly.

Comment: OK, what is $(2p)^3$ if you open the brackets? Is it divisible by 2? Can you divide it by 2 and tell the result?

Comment: @IvanNeretin $8p^3$?

Comment: Good! Now divide it by 2.

Comment: $4p^3$ which then became $2p^3$. Can't do it further I think.

Comment: There is no "then". Stop at $4p^3$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121054/discussion-between-roarke-and-ivan-neretin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is on the right lines but there are no words in it. You need to explain what you are doing to your readers. Here is how I would prove this:

- Assume, for the sake of contradiction, that there is a rational number $a$ such that $a^3=2$.
- Since $a$ is rational, we can write it in the form $m/n$, where $m$ and $n$ are coprime integers.
- This means that $$\frac{m^3}{n^3}=2 \, .$$
- From this we see that $m^3=2n^3$, and so $m^3$ is even. That implies that $m$ is even, i.e. it can be written in the form $2p$, where $p$ is an integer. It follows that
- $$\frac{8p^3}{n^3}=2$$
  which implies $2n^3=8p^3$ and so $n^3=4p^3=2(2p^3)$. Since $n^3$ is even, $n$ must also be even. But earlier we said that $m$ and $n$ are coprime, which is a contradiction. Hence, our original assumption—that there is a positive rational number $a$ such that $a^3=2$—must be false, meaning that no rational number satisfies the desired property.

Comment: This might be a little dumb of me to ask, but how do we know $m^3$ is even? In the book, the author just says that it is even, but doesn't explain why. He does say that because of a theorem if $a^2$ is even then $a$ is even. Did we just assume that $m^3$ is even?

Comment: @Roarke: Do you mean to ask why $m^3$ is even or why $m$ is even? $m^3$ is even because it equals $2n^3$. Since $m^3$ is $2\times\text{integer}$, it must be even, *by definition*.

Comment: Yeah was asking that $m^3$. I read this definition while searching some time ago but couldn't find it again. Thanks!

Comment: @Roarke: I'm happy to help. Here is a little advice: in mathematics definitions are *key*. If you don't have a precise understanding of what each term means, then this will inevitably lead to confusion. We know from a very young age that an even number is a number divisible by $2$. The formal way of writing this is that an even number is an integer that can be expressed in the form $2k$, where $k$ is an integer. Notice that a definition doesn't have to be written in logic symbols, either...

Comment: ...There's no advantage whatsoever in defining an even number as a number $n \in \mathbb{Z} \mid n=2k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Once you have the groundworks laid out, then everything will start falling into place.

Comment: I mess up with the definitions most of the time. It's kinda difficult. After trying it for a while and rereading the definition for a couple of time, I think I understand this one at least.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $m^3 = 2n^3$ implies that $m$ is even (is it clear why?). So you can take $m=2p$ for some $p$. Therefore:
$$
m^3 = 2n^3 \implies (2p)^3 = 2n^3 \implies 4p^3 = n^3.
$$
Because of the same reason, $n=2q$ for some $q$. Finally, use that $m$ and $n$ do not have common factors (you did not mention it in your question, but that is a key point).

Answer (score 1):

Alternative route:

Let $\alpha^3=2$, and assume $\alpha\in\Bbb Q$, then we have $$\frac{p^3}{q^3}=2\\p^3=2q^3\\p^3=q^3+q^3$$

The last line contradicts Fermat's Last Theorem.

---

> Let $x,y,z$ be non-zero integers. Then if $x^3+y^3=z^3$ we have $xyz=0$.

*Proof*: We can assume that $x,y,z$ are relatively prime, since if they were not we could divide by $\gcd(x,y,z)^3$.

Reducing the equation modulo $9$, and noticing that the only cubes are $0,-1,1$ we conclude that exactly one of $x,y,z$ is divisible by $9$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $9\mid z$.

We can factor the equation is question as $$z^3=(x+y)(x^2-xy+y^2)$$

Since $9\mid z^3$ we have that $3$ divides one of the factors $x+y, x^2-xy+y^2$. In fact, $3$ divides both of them as $$x^2-xy+y^2=(x+y)^2-3xy$$ That is, $3\mid x+y\iff 3\mid x^2-xy+y^2$. Since $3^3\mid z^3$ one of these factors are divisible by $9$ which will yield a contradiction:

- If $9\mid x^2-xy+y^2$ then $9\mid (x+y)^2-3xy$, so $9\mid 3xy$ which is impossible, as $x,y$ are assumed not to be divisible by $3$.
- If $9\mid x+y$, let $k$ be the highest power such that $3^k\mid x+y$, $k\geq 2$. Then we have $$3^{3k}\mid (x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$$ As $3^{3k}\mid x^3+y^3=z^3$, we have $$3^{3k}\mid 3xy(x+y)$$ This is impossible, since then $3^{2k-1}\mid xy$, and $2k-1\geq 3$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $a=p/q$, where $p$ and $q$ are not both even (or make the stronger assumption that $\gcd(p,q)=1$), and that $a^3=2$.  Then $(p/q)^3=2$, or $p^3=2q^3$.  Since the right-hand side is even, the left-hand side must be as well; and since the cube of an odd number is odd, $p$ must be even.  So $p=2p'$ for some integer $p'$.  Now $8(p')^3=2q^3$, or $q^3=4(p')^3$, and hence $q$ must be even as well.  This contradicts the original assumption, completing the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $ a=\frac pq $ with $gcd(p,q)=1$

$$p^3=2q^3\implies$$

$$(p-q)(p^2+pq+q^2)=q^3 \implies$$

$$q|( p^2+pq+q^2)\implies$$
$$q|p$$

Comment: How do you know that $q$ divides $p^2+pq+q^2$? $q$ may be composite.

Comment: $gcd(p-q,q)=gcd(p,q)=1$ and Gauss Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

This takes some setting up but, once that's done, the actual proof is pretty simple and easily visualized.

Let $\{p_1, p_2, p_3, \dots \}$ be the set of all positive prime numbers. We will assume that the $p_i$ are listed in increasing order.

Then every integer $n > 1$ can be expressed, **uniquely**, as an infinite product

$$n = \prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{\nu_i}$$

where the $\nu_i$ are non negative integers and only a finite number of them are not equal to $0$.

For example, $45 = 2^0 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^1 \cdot 7^0 \cdot 11^0 \cdot 13^0 \cdots$

Suppose

- $m$ and $n$ are positive integers
- $m = \prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{\mu_i}$
- $n = \prod_{i=1}^\infty p_i^{\nu_i}$
- $m^3 = 2 n^3$

The powers of $2$ in $m^3$ are $2^{3\mu_1}$.

The powers of $2$ in $2n^3$ are $2^{3\nu_1+1}$.

Hence $2^{3\mu_1} = 2^{3\nu_1+1}$. Hence $3\mu_1 = 3\nu_1+1$.

There do not exists integers $\mu_1$ and $\nu_1$
that will make $3\mu_1 = 3\nu_1+1$ true.

Hence $\sqrt[3] 2$ is an irrational number.